# "Souhaiteriez-vous y retourner, que ...": Does this conditional structure without "si" sound too formal?

Tags: conditionnel

> **Souhaiteriez**-vous y retourner, **que** vous y raccompagner **serait** mon plaisir !
>
> {or}: **Vous souhaiteriez** y retourner, **que** vous y raccompagner **serait** mon plaisir !

This particular conditional construction without "si" in favour of two Conditionnel Présent tenses with "que" placed in betweeen -- I wonder if it sounds too formal to be used in conversation?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes, it is very formal, that's definitely not something that would be used in a normal conversation. Not only the conditional without "si", but also the construction "*infinitive* serait mon plaisir" are not usually used in conversation. We would rather use something like:

> Si vous souhaitez y retourner, je vous raccompagnerais avec plaisir.

or more casual ("souhaiter" by itself is quite formal):

> Si vous voulez y retourner, je vous raccompagnerais avec plaisir.

Comment: Hi. I suppose the following expression, on the other hand, doesn't sound so formal? Because it's kind of an idiomatic expression? "On voudrait blanchir de l'argent qu'on ne s'y prendrait pas autrement."

Comment: Bonne réponse! +1 Il est intéressant que "souhaiter" seul soit formel. Mais je préfère le premier exemple.